# What is the equivalent of South's "schemamigration --update" for Django>=1.7?

Tags: django, django-south, django-migrations

When I was developing with South I was able to use the `--update` flag for the [schemamigration management command](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#schemamigration) to refine the latest migration.

This was very convenient for iterative development. Is there an equivalent of the `--update` flag for Django>=1.7 native migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doumentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations):

> You are encouraged to make migrations freely and not worry about how many you have; the migration code is optimized to deal with hundreds at a time without much slowdown.

If you really want to get rid of your migrations as you develop I think your best bet is to [squash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing) them.

Comment: If only I could select which migrations to squash (from and to), instead of having to squash all migrations until the one selected... To me, it doesn't make sense to have 10 migration files generated while prototyping, while this could be reduced to one and be much cleaner. My current process for development is simply to migrate back, delete the last migration file and generate a new one. But it would be nicer if this was done automatically like in South with a flag.

Comment: I agree. I'm looking forward to seeing a better option too. I wanted to have the reference to the documentation up here for the future though.

Comment: I've opened https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24870#ticket asking for this feature.